# What is the meaning of "humbler walls"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, writing-style, metaphors

I'm totally confused about this sentence; its grammar seems crazy. Please help me to understand it. It is from a documentary film about ancient history I've watched.

> Life wasn't easy for ordinary Egyptians, but order was infinitely better than disorder. We all remember the pyramids and pharaohs, but advances which were, in the long term, just as significant were being made behind humbler walls. (0:49:41.60)
>
> <sub>source: Andrew Marr’s [History of the World](http://tvguide.lastown.com/bbc/preview/andrew-marrs-history-of-the-world/1-survival.html) – Age of Survival</sub>

What are *humbler walls*? As I have watched the whole film, I think the meaning is:

> Although pyramids and pharaohs were better developed than ordinary Egyptians, the significant advanced inventions of history were made by the ordinary Egyptians rather than by those pharaohs and pyramids.

What do you think about it?

Comment: First look up "humble".  Then think: how can a wall be humble?

Comment: Please can you use correct capitalisation in future. I have corrected it for you this time. Thanks.

Comment: The most rememberable/notable things in the Egypt history are Pyramids and Pharaohs. People remember these *two* while they don't remember/recognize those advances (which were as significant as those *two*) made by *ordinary* Egyptians.

Comment: The pyramids are enormous, elaborate structures to honor rulers who were revered as gods. That's about as far from humble as a structure can be.  A building that is used for storing turnips would not be remembered or revered in the same way, therefore it's a "humbler" building. "Behind humbler walls" means "behind walls that are not considered famous or important." However suppose some turnip warehouse keeper devised a new method for tallying turnips, which led to a new way of using mathematics? That would be a significant advance that came about "behind humbler walls.

Comment: @barbecue - No, it would be a significant advance that came about behind *humble* walls. Unless you claim that advances happened behind pyramid walls -- but you seem to deny that in your comment on my answer. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - The walls of the turnip warehouse were humbler than the walls of the pyramids (and, by implication, the walls of the pharaohs' palaces) to which they were being compared.

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm really trying to understand why so many think this is acceptable but I still don't see it. Some people are saying  that the pharoahs and the pyramids are themselves the advances.  Others are saying that the pyramids and  (implied) palaces are the grander walls. If the former then you cannot say that walls are humbler than advances (apples and pears). If the latter then you can compare them but you have to believe that advances were made behind pyramid walls (which I don't believe because pyramids were tombs not laboratories). Does not compute.  Exterminate!!!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Yeah, kill all the poets!  The wording is every so slightly metaphorical, which makes it, in my view, more pleasant to read.

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm all for poets but this one needs to have  their poetic license revoked. As far as I am concerned this is a case of DUI and just short of a car crash.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I don't see why you are getting your shorts in a knot because you failed to understand a metaphor.  (In fact, I suspect you understand it now, but don't want to admit that to yourself.)

Comment: As I have repeatedly said, we all understand precisely what the 'poet' is trying to say. My point all along is that it is a linguistic disaster and therefore I sympathise with the OP's dismay.  By the way, I see that alongside me and the OP there is a new voice on the side of sanity. I actually have an up-vote now.  Who knows, given time, I may achieve zero once more. Onwards and upwards!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm not trying to have it both ways, you're simply creating unnecessary and irrelevant things to complain about that were never said, either in the original quote, or in anything I wrote.

Comment: Joining in the fun :) I'm not very good at punctuation, I have been accused of splicing my sentences more than once, so what  I am about to suggest could be utterly wrong. But, is the punctuation 100% correct? Is there a website which transcripts the commentary/documentary? Because, personally, I would have added a period (full stop) after *pharaohs* and started a new sentence with *but*. Some might complain that sentences cannot begin with a conjunction, but better writers than I commit this "sin".

Comment: Looking over the (many) corrections made to this question, which have improved it considerably, I don't think the OP is in a position to say the offending sentence is grammatically crazy. Perhaps a little more humility is in order here.

Answer (score 5):

> We all remember the pyramids and pharaohs, but advances which were, in the long term, just as significant were being made behind humbler walls

The **grammar** is not "crazy".

We can take out the parenthetical phrase "in the long term". We can remove the adjectival phrase "which were just as significant".

> We all remember the pyramids and pharaohs, but advances were being made behind humbler walls.

It's a picturesque metaphorical phrase, almost poetic, likening the monumental faces of the pyramids to walls. And *humble* doesn't necessarily mean "deferent":

> (Of a thing) of modest pretensions or dimensions:
>   *he built the business empire from humble beginnings*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humble)

So, in a sentence which is far more prosaic,

> We may all remember the great buildings and their builders, but long-lasting and significant advances were also being made in buildings of lower status and smaller size.

Comment: I agree that the grammar is correct. It is just the semantics that are nonsensical. You either seem to think that advances were being made in the great buildings (in this case the pyramids) or you have left the phrase 'lower status' hanging. The buildings are of lower size and status than what?

Comment: Advances just as significant as the engineering achievements developed over the pyramids' history were being made in humbler buildings [than the pyramids.] See barbecue's comment on the question. I thought my answer said that. Maybe not clearly enough.

Comment: I understand what the sentence is *supposed* to mean -- as we all do. I didn't see the documentary and I'm guessing this was an off-the-cuff  remark that someone made. None of us speak in perfect prose and it's quite excusable if it wasn't an ideally turned phrase.  I am addressing the OP's puzzlement and explaining that the sentence does not bear strict scrutiny and so the OP should not be concerned about finding it difficult to understand in linguistic terms.

Answer (score -2):

**Humbler walls**

The walls in question are humble in the sense that they are *lowly* and unpretentious and they are *low* in the sense that they are not as tall as those of the grand palaces and pyramids.

I do however question the use of the comparative 'humbler'. It is not clear to me what they are supposed to be humbler than.

> We all remember the pyramids and pharaohs, but advances which were, in the long term, just as significant were being made behind humbler walls.

There are problems with this sentence. Either it

1. implies that pharoahs have (or are) walls!

or it

2. implies that advances were being made behind the walls of pyramids. That is rather dubious. Pyramids were tombs -- there wasn't much going on behind their walls once said walls had been built.  [This claim is challenged, explored further, and I believe justified by me in the comments below]

A quick reading of the sentence yields its meaning. As you say, it suggests that ordinary people were making advances -- not just the great engineers who were responsible for the pharaohs' pyramids and palaces.

I don't agree that the grammar is crazy. It is quite possible to say erroneous or meaningless things and still speak in perfectly good grammar. Instead I would say that the sentence does not stand up to strict linguistic analysis from the point of view of its semantics.

EDIT 13 Oct 2015

I have amended the wording of this answer in response to some of the comments below. I still believe that the sentence in question is infelicitous and my reasons are given here and in the comments.

Comment: It doesn't imply that pharaohs have or are walls, or that advances happened inside pyramids. The pyramids and pharaohs are themselves examples of cultural achievements. Other achievements happened too, which were less spectacular, but just as important in the long term.

Comment: @barbecue - I'm sorry but your logic is faulty. The writer does not say that the walls themselves are advances but that the advances are made within the walls. These walls (within which the advances were made) are humbler than something -- but what is the something? Is it other walls? If not, then what can it be? You have not explained that and neither has the author. Please can you do so, then maybe I'll concede the point.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK The walls are the ones humbler than the funerary monuments that pharaohs have.  We call them pyramids.  There were most certainly achievements made behind pyramid walls, including the engineering of concealed burial chambers, the artistic decorations of the tombs, the medical processes of ancient embalming, and the literary lithoglyphics.

Comment: +1 In my opinion the pairing of pyramids and pharaohs as advances is problematic, even if you don't infer (as a fair-minded reader reasonably might) from the sentence's structure that pyramids and pharaohs were made behind less humble walls than the ones behind which equally significant advances were being made.

Comment: @deadrat - Um... The burial chambers were not constructed behind the walls. That would have required hollow pyramids - a feat that would have been beyond even the ingenious Egyptians. The burial chambers were built in the open and the walls were later constructed around them. I'm aware of no evidence that the embalming was done inside the pyramids.  The hieroglyphics and decorations were *executed* inside the pyramids but both technologies were invented well before that so they weren't advances that were made behind  pyramid walls.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Um, yes the burial chambers were constructed within the pyramids, which is to say behind their "walls."  Go here for a diagram: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e4/33/75/e4337518ff162d68809a8ebe6dfa0e40.jpg  These were ingeniously made to foil grave robbers.  Is the metaphorical meaning of "humbler walls" really so unclear to you?

Comment: @barbecue You are the master of your own time and attention.  No one can drive you from a cyberforum.  It's a simple matter to ignore that which you find unworthy.  I think chasly is being somewhat obtuse about the meaning of the passage, but I don't think anything he's written is nasty.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK You have managed to offend someone.  I think barbecue has taken offense rather than your giving it.  (Certainly, I'm not offended by anything you've written to me.)  But it's not an achievement, and it's nothing to gloat about.  I hope you'll consider deleting your "Thanks" comment, if only to keep my comments about you true.

Comment: Okay, deleted. It was intended as a riposte rather than a gloat but point taken. That diagram doesn't show anything about the order in which things were built. Are you saying that the pyramids were built first and that the burial chambers were excavated afterwards? That seems to indicate a big oversight.

Comment: @SvenYargs  I don't understand.  What would lead a reader, fair- or bloody-minded, to infer that pyramids and pharaohs were made behind less humble walls?  Even the literal-minded would infer (courtesy of the conjunction *but*) that p's and p's were made behind unhumble walls?  Wouldn't the not-so-literal-minded conclude that the admonition to remember concerns the advances of pyramid builders and their rulers?

Comment: @deadrat - I don't think this will ever be resolved but I'll have one last go.  The sentence says in part (I'll be selective for my own purposes but I won't change any words or their order), "We all remember the ... pharaohs, but advances ... were being made behind humbler walls."    This is a non-sequitur. It's a little like saying, "We all remember President Bush but queues were forming outside other cinemas." At which point I ask why you use the word 'other' when no cinemas have previously been mentioned. Also I wonder what function the word 'but' serves. Is President Bush a cinema?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Thanks for indulging me.  I hope barbecue returns in the conviction that no one can force him to leave.  I don't know how the burial chambers were constructed, after the blocks are laid or before.  In either case, a considerable feat of engineering.  Allow me to change your example somewhat:  "We all remember President Bush and his  White House, but the decision to torture prisoners of war was made in less-lofty offices."  I don't think it's a stretch to link Pharaohs and accomplishments any more than it is to link W with failed policies.

Comment: Okay, that's bordering on the acceptable now. However I still see two problems. It wouldn't have been so good with,  "We all remember the White House and President Bush, but the decision to torture prisoners of war was made in less-lofty offices." Also the presence of 'but' is a mystery. Example: "We all remember the White House but we don't remember less-lofty offices."  That's fine but, "We all remember the White House but the decision to torture was made elsewhere." Those are two unrelated facts (1) we remember and (2) a decision was made. There is no'but' about it.

Comment: It is always a good idea, (talking from personal experience) to look for the original source to check whether the OP has correctly transcribed a script and its punctuation. It's also helpful to see whether the author of the piece is a native speaker, a professional writer etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for that reminder -- and for adding the relevant information to the question. I'll look again and see if it causes me to amend my answer :-)

Comment: Blimey, I'm reluctant to pipe up here...  The OP quote **does not** suggest that 'pyramids' and 'Pharoahs' were *advances*, only that they were *significant*. I think we can agree that neither are *humble*. It's perfectly reasonable to claim that other things, for example 'advances', may have been just as significant. Likewise, that those things may have originated somewhere more humble that those two phenomena. That's all. Sorry if this has all been examined elsewhere, but it's a convoluted thread...

Comment: @JHCL - You say, "may have originated somewhere more humble that those two phenomena".  There is a problem of logic there. Pharaohs and pyramids also originated from humble beginnings.

Comment: The comparison isn't with where P & p came from historically. It's with their *current* status in our wider cultural understanding. But even if it weren't, it's an argument of 'degree of humility', then, surely? Not logic.